# Is there some index/list for community wiki questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-wiki

Is there some page on which I can access `community-wiki` questions for a tag. I believe that the questions that are added to community wiki, specifically by the moderators discuss some important aspects about a topic.

I searched but could not find any index of the questions marked as community-wiki.

As a tag can have a lot of questions marked as community-wiki, having an index for all community questions might not be a good-idea. However, I think some subset of these questions can be added to the tag wiki, per se.

Some `community-wiki` questions that I think can be added to tag-wikis(or something else) are the ones which:

- are added by trusted users. (or some other benchmark on reputation)
- are added by moderators.
- have high a really number of views.
- have high a really number of votes.

I feel that this will better server the purpose.

Any comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for `[tag name] wiki:1`.

Comment: thanks. never knew of it. Is there a way to sort them as well, may be by number of revisions/votes/sthg?

Comment: Revisions, no. Votes, yes... you just search for it and click on the "Votes" tab to sort it in descending order. If you want other custom options, you might have to use the [data.se]